# Movie where lightning brings people back to life as "blue people"

Tags: story-identification, movie

I have been looking for this movie over the past 6 years and I could never find it.

It is an Asian sci/fi, romance, war movie. I think it started where a young man (protagonist) was in a war. As his team stormed a house, there they were some civilians and he was ordered to shoot them (execute). As he was thinking on the request the officer pointed a gun at him and made him choose his life or the life of the civilians, of course he shot them.

The next scene I remember, there was a pile of corpses (maybe the protagonist was also in the pile), point being a metallic lightning (basically a rod that was in the shape of a lighting) strikes in the pile, stayed there and people started to get back to life, just their skin was blue, blueish.

Normal people didn't like them or were scared of them etc. The movie continues as these revived people are looking for salvation, which supposedly resides in an ancient mountain full of killer robots, an unstoppable mechanical army. These people are led by the protagonist.

He finds the mountain and gets godlike armour, which allows him to have tremendous strength etc. He then fights for the rights of blue people and leading them to safety... or so I remember. Over the whole movie he has a girlfriend or falling in love with a girl (not a blue person).

Does anyone know what this movie is?

---

The most epic scene in the movie is when the protagonist learns of the powers of the armour and uses it to fight the robots off, protecting normal humans.

The pile of bodies was placed in a big, dark space that seemed like a Temple, with pillars and this big pool at the start or the stairs where all the bodies were dumped.

Comment: Welcome to SFF! Yuo have a very nice start here, however, can you take a look at [this guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/58193) and see if there is anything else you can [edit] in? For example, you say you've been searching for it for 6 years but do you know when you saw it?

Comment: Yeah I was a kid back then I really cannot remember could have been like 10+ years ago :). I have a bad grasp on getting old and counting time.

Comment: The blue skin makes me think of jiangshi (Chinese hopping vampires), but I think you'd mention if they hopped around. So there were guns as well as magic revival and armor?

Comment: Yes as mentioned there was a war going on. The weapons were from WW2, it seemed. The execution scene had  Luger pistol. Yes and even the armor could make him fly and big killer robots. Oh and no the blue people behaved exactly as any other. They wanted their lives back but people feared them.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Pretty sure this is [Casshern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casshern_(film)). Movie is from 2004, in an early scene the protagonist is ordered to massacre some civilians and is later killed himself. He is later revived as part of an event which creates a bunch of zombie-esq "Neo humans" or "Neo Sapiens", these are revived dead people created through a combination of macabre experiments in genetic engineering and a giant stone lightning bolt. The giant stone lightning bolt comes as a surprise to everyone involved.

The movie is good, but quite odd and hard to describe.

The lightning bolt:

[image: Lightning bolt]

The armour:

[image: Armour]

The Massacre:

[image: Massacre]

Unstoppable mechanical army:

[image]

Comment: AMAZING! Thank  you so much. I almost gave up hope in finding it. You really made my day. Thanks again :)

Comment: Definitely right about *Casshern* being hard to describe. It's a mixture of steampunk, apocalyptic war, mad science resurrections, and with an unstoppable superhero slaughtering armies opposing him. This is combined with a frankly weird set of love and family entanglements. Fascinating and strange yet oddly good. It's made for those fateful words: *What did I just watch?*